# rendering complex models [states] with amperstand.js views [subviews]

Tags: javascript, ampersand.js

- by a marionette\backbone developer trying (hard) to adopt ampersand

Given a complex model with nested properties (below). what is the best practice to render a deeply nested layout.

-- mainView

---- userInfoView

------ socialInfoView

-------- socialCollectionsView

ampersand state don't support **"deep model"**. it seem fairly flat (one level and then you can your own type like 'reviewModel'). <- i want to avoid creating these new types. i know there is a children 'thing' but i don't think it applies.

**Basically, how can i keep my complex model without breaking it and have my nested (views/subviews) layout clear and readable.**

```js
{
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe',
  "social": {
    "linkedin": {
      "connections": 123,
      "positions": [{
        image: 'bla.jpg'
        "title": "CTO & Co - founder"
      }, {
        image: 'bla2.jpg'
        "title": "prime minister"
      }, ],
      "friends": [{
        name: james,
        a: 'b'
      }, {
        name: jane,
        x: 'y'
      }],
      "languages": ['english', 'russian']
    },
    "twitter": {
      "connections": 122
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to watch for changes in the deep data, then you could simply use the 'object' data type for props like 'social' and access like so `this.model.social.linkedin.connections` in your view.

Otherwise, you do need to use the [children hash](https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-state/blob/master/ampersand-state.js#L496-L503) (code) or the ['state' data type](https://github.com/AmpersandJS/ampersand-state/blob/master/ampersand-state.js#L740-L770) (code) because they auto-set listeners.

Ampersand *does* require you to be explicit about things (the new types you are trying to avoid) when you want to observe changes in deeply nested data.

The Ampersand way is to prefer small, single-concern models/views wherever possible and to compose the unavoidably complex ones from small, single-concern ones.

Answer (score 0):

"state.children" might be what you are looking for. Or try "props" of type 'state'.

Comment: i re-read the docs again. i think what they expect me to do is to indeed break each level to a child property. this may create a lot entities since not all are pure collections or states. 
```
socialModel ->
----children: socialCollection
-----------------socialCollectionItemModel
--------------------------socialCollectionItemModelNewCollection

Comment: Ampersand is twisting your arm slightly to do this (to break it down to simplify it in views, forms etc.), and IMHO that is a good thing, as when things evolve you will get many small pieces in you puzzle, not big ones. (also, plz accept my [short] answer, I need to get enough point here to upvote/downvote =)